# Typescript, how to use class as type for an argument

Tags: class, types, typescript

I'm trying to understand how typescript works.
I have file with class, e.g.:

```
export class Aclass {

}
```

And there is another class in another file:

```
export class Bclass {

    constructor(private a:Aclass) {

    }
}
```

This give an error about unresoved type.
What is a right way to do this?

UPDATE: Is there way to avoid importing in all files?

Comment: you need to import it in your Bclass file too. Check out this link on es6 modules. http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html

Comment: So I need to do importing all the time in all files? Is there other way?

Comment: Ok, but if I make module with interface? It make actually what I need. But in this case I don't understand how to import class to use it in angular.

Comment: I mean this way export interface IMessagesService extends MessagesService{}

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.. you can export just about anything you want.. and import it as well. If you have a question on a specific issue please make a question for that issue as well. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105397/discussion-between-toskv-and-frione).

Answer (score 1):

You could use namespaces aka internal modules. Each namespace creates a global variable, so I wouldn't recommend it. External modules using export and import is the better way to go. If you must use namespaces:

file1.ts:

```
namespace main {
    export class First{
    name: string;
  }
}
```

file2.ts

```
namespace main {
  class Two {
    second: First;

    constructor() {
      this.second = new First();
      this.second.name = 'second name';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the Aclass into the Bclass file which would look something like this:

```
///Bclass.js
import Aclass = require('./Aclass.js') //require should be relative path to Aclass from Bclass

export class Bclass {

    constructor(private a:Aclass) {

    }
}
```

See the "Going External" section of the TypeScript docs: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook